# How to use this xml drawable as progressbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawable

i had this xml

https://pastebin.com/URDhBjJC

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:width="256.000000dp"
   android:height="160.000000dp"
   android:viewportWidth="256.000000"
   android:viewportHeight="160.000000">

    <group
       android:translateY="160.000000"
       android:scaleX="0.100000"
       android:scaleY="-0.100000">
        <path
           android:fillColor="#000000"
           android:strokeWidth="1"
           android:pathData="M1930 1565 c-91 -31 -123 -49 -188 -110 -54 -50 -132 -177 -132 -216 0 -12 -55 -14 -345 -15 -244 0 -345 3 -345 10 0 29 -65 140 -112 191 -44 49 -139 116 -165 117 -4 0 -16 4 -26 10 -47 25 -195 35 -269 18 -129 -30 -255 -134 -315 -258 l-35 -74 4 -146 c4 -129 8 -152 28 -192 13 -25 32 -55 43 -67 19 -21 19 -22 -7 -56 -48 -62 -66 -134 -66 -254 1 -71 6 -122 16 -148 8 -22 16 -44 17 -50 2 -5 6 -16 10 -23 5 -6 14 -22 20 -35 7 -12 45 -53 84 -90 79 -73 126 -99 233 -124 25 -6 158 -5 168 1 5 3 24 8 43 11 56 9 138 55 201 113 32 30 58 58 58 64 0 5 13 29 29 52 16 23 33 58 38 77 l9 34 342 3 c320 2 343 1 348 -15 23 -73 64 -135 135 -206 43 -42 82 -76 86 -75 5 1 18 -3 30 -10 113 -63 289 -62 423 1 44 20 180 141 180 160 0 5 9 22 21 38 11 16 22 37 24 46 3 10 12 47 21 83 15 62 15 137 -1 215 -8 40 -62 150 -81 166 -13 10 -12 15 4 33 17 18 44 62 48 76 0 3 3 12 7 20 27 69 38 199 23 265 -10 47 -40 121 -61 154 -34 54 -144 154 -195 178 -111 53 -245 63 -350 28z m221 -200 c161 -55 230 -244 144 -391 -14 -24 -41 -55 -59 -69 -70 -53 -65 -108 17 -188 58 -57 87 -121 87 -196 0 -98 -83 -213 -176 -245 -163 -55 -317 42 -358 228 -27 120 14 111 -507 114 -297 2 -463 -1 -489 -8 -46 -12 -70 -43 -77 -97 -16 -143 -128 -253 -258 -254 -78 -1 -128 17 -183 66 -69 62 -96 127 -90 216 6 80 38 141 98 189 45 35 60 83 39 121 -7 13 -31 41 -54 61 -143 126 -106 359 69 439 150 68 346 -44 372 -213 4 -23 13 -55 20 -69 28 -56 9 -54 508 -51 254 2 470 6 481 9 36 10 54 34 61 82 18 126 86 217 186 252 65 23 111 24 169 4z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

I would like the bone to go according to the percentage.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your link isn't opening up but I have described taking an example

Customizing a ProgressBar requires defining the attribute or properties for the background and progress of your progress bar.

Create an XML file named customprogressbar.xml in your res->drawable folder:

custom_progressbar.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#000001"
                android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#0d1522"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
   </item>

  <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now you need to set the progressDrawable property in customprogressbar.xml (drawable)

You can do this in the XML file or in the Activity (at run time).

Do the following in your XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

At run time do the following

```
// Get the Drawable custom_progressbar                     
    Drawable draw=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
// set the drawable as progress drawable
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
```